# 2-way slider for Android

Tags: android, slider, range

I'm trying to make a slider with ability to select 2 points just like selecting a range from the slider.

[image: Slider]

Did anyone do anything like that?

Comment: Are you actually having trouble with something, or do you want someone to write your code for you?

Comment: looking arround for a tutorial? if none is found i would have to code it myself

Comment: some thing like this 

http://www.flickr.com/photos/11195624@N05/4906951542/

Comment: Try this https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with SeekBar... it has progress and secondary progress... just subclass it and override the methods to do what you want

Comment: that is a progress bar thing primary and secondary , how can that be used as dual slider control?

Comment: well if it can't then I am not exactly sure what you are talking about... do you have a picture of a "dual slider control"?

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/photos/11195624@N05/4906951542/

i have uploaded a cropped photo of iphone app, I want to make this for android, thanks

Comment: I looks like you will have to write a custom widget for that... It's almost like a ruler type of control... While this isn't anything like what you are looking for... there is a project called Ringdroid that has a custom widget with a custom widget that has 2 independent sliders to select a time frame in a media file to cut a custom ringtone out. You may be able to at least get an idea of how to start by looking at that code. http://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/